# Default JQuery UI datepicker to first available date in collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following date picker setup so that only the dates in the available dates collection defined in the page can be selected:

```
var availableDates = ["08-12-2015","29-12-2015"];

$('.departureDate').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: departureDates,
    onSelect: filterInstances,
    altField: '#uniformDate',
    altFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    defaultDate: get_default_date
});

function departureDates(date) {
   // Change the format of the date for local independent comparison
   var dmy = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
   if (availableDates.indexOf(dmy) == -1) {
     return [false];
   } else {
     return [true];
   }
}

function get_default_date() {
    var date = new Date(availableDates[0])
    return date;
}
```

The problem I have now is that my date picker won't default to the first available date.

In my Firebug console i receive the following error using the code shown above:

> TypeError: i.getTime is not a function
>   http://localhost:54044/scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js Line 8

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

jezzipin

Comment: Shouldn't you call `getDefaultDate()` instead of passing it? `defaultDate: get_default_date()`?

Comment: can you create fiddle/snippet ?

Comment: Just in the process of doing so @KrupeshKotecha

Answer (score 1):

For all of those interested in this post, this was the solution:

```
$('.departureDate').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: departureDates,
    onSelect: filterInstances,
    altField: '#uniformDate',
    altFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    defaultDate: get_default_date()
});

function departureDates(date) {
    // Change the format of the date for local independent comparison
    var dmy = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
    if (availableDates.indexOf(dmy) == -1) {
        return [false];
    } else {
        return [true];
    }
}

function get_default_date() {
    var date = availableDates[0];
    date = date.split("-");
    date = new Date(date[2], date[1] - 1, date[0]);
    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke `get_default_date`.

Replace:

```
defaultDate: get_default_date
```

With:

```
defaultDate: get_default_date()
```

`get_default_date` returns the function. `get_default_date()` returns whatever the function returns, so in this case, the default date.

Also, your date strings are formatted incorrectly. Instead of `dd-mm-yyyy`, the `Date` constructor expects `mm-dd-yyyy`.

Replace:

```
var availableDates = ["08-12-2015","29-12-2015"];
```

With:

```
var availableDates = ["12-08-2015","12-29-2015"];
```

Comment: The first available date is the 8th December. With the code above, the datepicker defaults to November.

Comment: @kitler I have been developing in Javascript for years so don't need a guide. It's this particular datepicker that is the problem.

Comment: No, the datepicker isn't the problem, it's your date strings. They're parsed as `dd-mm-yyyy` instead of your format, which is `mm-dd-yyyy`

Comment: My format is dd-mm-yyyy. There are not 29 months in a year.

Comment: Eh, good morning, I'm clearly not quite awake yet. It's the other way around, JS expects `mm-dd-yyyy`

Comment: @Cerberus I am afraid I cannot do that. This is a multi-lingual site so we have to default the dates to a common date format. In this case, it is uk date format. The date filtering works correctly so javascript can understand the format I am giving it, it's just the defaultdate bit that is the problem

Comment: The `Date` constructor doesn't accept a localized format. And since it returns a `Date` object, I really don't see how the date format input in the code is even relevant...

Comment: I'm sorry but if that were the case my current code that filters the dates available in the datepicker would not be working.

Comment: Right. So, you seem to have a choice: fix the filtering code to use date objects, or "fix" the date picker.

Answer (score -1):

The date format you are using is wrong.

08-12-2015 became : Wed Aug 12 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST) and is not in the valid date range.

29-12-2015 is invalid.